# Como salvar itens do spinner no firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, mobile, spinners

sou iniciante em android studio e travei em uma parte, já procurei aqui no stack vi algumas possíveis soluções mas não funcionaram pra mim, não sei se é por causa do meu código, vamos lá, tenho 2 spinners que recebem os dados do firebase para complementar um formulário, não estou conseguindo salvar esse formulário com os dados selecionados no spinner.
se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei imensamente grato.
(obs.: se alguém puder me ensinar como organizar melhor o codigo, também agradeço.

```
public class CadastroServicos extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    EditText numeroPedido;
    Spinner nomeParceiroServico;
    Spinner tipoServicoServico;
    EditText cliente;
    EditText produto;
    EditText quantidade;
    EditText precoPago;
    EditText dataEnvio;
    ArrayList<String> item;

    DatabaseReference dbReferenceParceiro;
    DatabaseReference dbReferenceServico;

    ValueEventListener listenerParceiro;
    ValueEventListener listenerServico;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterParceiro;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterServico;

    ArrayList<String> spinnerListParceiro;
    ArrayList<String> spinnerListServico;


    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_servicos);

        numeroPedido = findViewById(R.id.editNumeroPedido);
        nomeParceiroServico = findViewById(R.id.spinnerParceiro);
        tipoServicoServico = findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoServico);
        cliente = findViewById(R.id.editCliente);
        produto = findViewById(R.id.editProduto);
        quantidade = findViewById(R.id.editQuantidade);
        precoPago = findViewById(R.id.editPrecoPago);
        dataEnvio = findViewById(R.id.editDataEnvio);


        dbReferenceParceiro = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Parceiro");
        spinnerListParceiro = new ArrayList<>();
        adapterParceiro = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CadastroServicos.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerListParceiro);


        dbReferenceServico = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TipoServico");
        spinnerListServico = new ArrayList<>();
        adapterServico = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CadastroServicos.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerListServico);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CadastroServicos.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerListParceiro);

        nomeParceiroServico.setAdapter(adapterParceiro);
        tipoServicoServico.setAdapter(adapterServico);


        retrieveData();
        inicializaFirebase();
        inicializaFirebase2();

    }
```